# Delta filter stops working for the email messages

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-files

We use 'delta' ms graph api to track the changes in the message.

Accordingly microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages we can use delta parameter in such from '$filter=receivedDateTime+ge+{value}'

After the some recent change from MS site with have following error everywhere

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXX@YYY.ZZZ/mailFolders('inbox')/messages/delta?$filter=receivedDateTime%20ge%202022-09-25T00%3A00%3A00Z&$select=receivedDateTime,isDraft,internetMessageId,subject
```

Transcript

```
<= GET /users/XXX@YYY.ZZZ/mailFolders('inbox')/messages/delta?$filter=receivedDateTime%20ge%202022-09-25T00%3A00%3A00Z&$select=receivedDateTime,isDraft,in...
=> 400 {"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidUrlQuery", "message":"The '$filter' parameter value is not supported for 'Messages' resource; only a value of 'receivedDateTime ge value' is supported."} }
```

As you can see filter is the exactly as in docs. Please help!!!

Comment: Now the "Microsoft Community" (aka answers.microsoft.com) marking this message  as a harassment??? I hope that the ms support still has a sane engineers who able to answer the question here.